# Node.js + Nginx Access-Control-Allow-Origin not working

Tags: nginx, node.js

I have an api hosted on `api.mysite.com` and a client on `client.mysite.com`. Now from client I get

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   `http://api.mysite.com/settings/find`.
>   Origin `http://client.mysite.com` is not allowed by
>   Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

The api is build on node.js (sailsjs framework) and the client on angular.js. The webserver is a **nginx** machine. My vhost config:

```
server {
    listen 0.0.0.0:80;
    server_name api.mysite.com;

    location / {
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' 'http://api.mysite.com';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'X-Requested-With,Accept,Content-Type, Origin';

        proxy_pass         http://127.0.0.1:1337/;
        proxy_redirect     off;

        proxy_set_header   Host             $host;
        proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
}
```

So in browser I can access my api very well, however when I access it from client I get above error. As you can see I added relevant headers to the vhost, however I still get the error. Any ideas whats wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved my own problem. Replaced

```
add_header
```

with

```
proxy_set_header
```

:)

Comment: Use ``add_header`` inside ``if`` clause.

Comment: @CppLearner No, avoid `if` clause inside `location` block. https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/